# how do i know my byte array containing blank .tif file or not

Tags: c#, image

i have a application where i need to check my scanner generates blank tif file or not.
here i share my example code

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path2 = @"F:\3333.tif";
        string path = @"F:\Document Scanned @ 1-blank.tif";
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path);
        byte[] bytes;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);
            bytes = ms.ToArray();
        }

        System.Drawing.Image img2 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path2);
        byte[] bytes2;

        using (MemoryStream ms3 = new MemoryStream())
        {
            img2.Save(ms3, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);
            bytes2 = ms3.ToArray();
        }
        bool t = false;
        t = bytes.SequenceEqual(bytes2);
    }
```

Note: Blank tif image meance white page .

<s>In above bool t always returns true why ? i used two diff images</s> solved

Comment: Please explain the problem with your example code.

Comment: what do you men by *blank*: all pixels blank, all pixel almost blank or almost all pixel almost blank

Comment: any way to identify blank (simple white ) page in tif format .

Comment: I've not used it myself, but just to throw in an idea; the pnmcrop tool (http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pnmcrop.html) will remove the whitespace from an image, you could try it on your blank scans and I'm thinking it'll reduce the input tif file down to something small. Possibly you might need to use pbmclean (http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pbmclean.html) to remove any small speckles from the image too. If the resulting file is small (in terms of x/y dimensions) then it'll probably be a safe bet that it doesn't contain any useful content.

Comment: @Aditya: In your last edit you changed 'img.Save(..)' to 'img2.Save(..)'. I guess that should have solved your problem that 'bool t' contained the wrong value, right?

Comment: @cortex42 yes but i still searching how i compere white blank page to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you are comparing the bytes of two TIF files (with the indirection of using `Image`). This can fail for various reasons:

**Dimension**: If the two images do not have the exact same height and width, the byte sequences will -of course- be different even if both are completely white.

**Metadata**: As far as I know, the TIF format contains various metadata. Therefore, two files may be different even if they have the same pixels. I would recommend manually checking all pixel values (e.g. `Bitmap.GetPixel`) and comparing them to white (`Color.FromArgb(255,255,255,255)`).

**Noise**: Are you sure that a blank file is always pure white `(255,255,255)`? Maybe some random pixels have slightly different values such as `(255,254,255)`...